# How can i solve font-weight, text too bold, in safari or mac when compared to other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, safari

I have used "Levenim MT" font in my website. Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and others relevant browsers is right. But problem in MAC and Safari browsers font-size and weight is too much to any other browsers.Now what can i do?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'levenim_mt';
  src: url('../fonts/levenim_mt.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/levenim_mt.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/levenim_mt.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/levenim_mt.ttf') format('truetype');

}

body{
  font-family: 'levenim_mt', sans-serif;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  clear: both;
}
```

My site in: [enter link description here](http://appbajar.xyz/newhtml/user.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well this error is new and unique for me but i am aware about 1 css hack through which you can write css specificly for mac

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') > 0)
$('body').addClass('mac-os');

body.mac-os{
  font-family: 'levenim_mt', sans-serif;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: //font weight for mac you want;
  font-size: //font size for mac you want;
}
```

This will only apply above css in mac